# Zend_Db_Table "where" for relations?

Tags: php, where-clause, zend-db-table, relation

Hello all
Is `Zend_Db_Table` (`Zend_Db_Table_*`) supports `where` for related data that defined through `$_referenceMap` / `$_dependentTable`

As example, i have Blogs (table: blogs) and Regions (table: regions) classes, each Blog have region_id:

```
|-------------|              |--------------|
| regions     |              | blogs        |
|-------------| 1     :    m |--------------|
| region_id   | <----------- | region_id    |
| region_name |              | blog_id      |
|-------------|              | blog_message |
                             | blog_enabled |
                             |--------------|
```

And is there any way to do, something like:

```
$a = new Regions();
$a->fetchRow(1)->findBlogs(..., $a->getAdapter()->quoteInto('blog_enabled = ?', 1));
```

i.e. find `Region` with `region_id == 1`, then find all `Blogs`, that belongs to `Region`, and have `blog_enabled == 1`

Comment: If you have a Row object as the result of a query on a parent table, you can fetch rows from dependent tables that reference the current row. Use the method:

    $row->findDependentRowset($table, [$rule]);

quoted from this page http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

Comment: yup, but there's no way to specify `where` conds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$a = new News();
$a->fetchRow()->findParentRegions($a->select()->where('region_enabled = ?', 1));
```